# bootstrap image row out of place

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[SOLVED]

I'm have written a horizontal row of 4 images 500x300 using placeholders, this works perfectly fine, but when I try to replace those images with images from a folder (using php) of the same dimensions, the first 2 image containes are knocked out of place while the last 2 are where they belong.. I've attached a screenshot and the code below is what I'm using to get the row of images.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top:1px">
<?php
$directory = 'images';
if (! is_dir($directory)) {
exit('Invalid diretory path');
}
$files = array();
foreach (scandir($directory) as $file) {
?>

<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6" >
<a href="#" >
<img  class="img-responsive portfolio-item" src="<?php echo "images/$file"; ?>" alt="">
</a>
</div>

<?php
}
?>

</div>
```

[this is what i get in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fbl8.png)

Comment: I dont know much about PHP but it seems that you should have this `<img  class="img-responsive portfolio-item" src="<?php echo 'images/$file'; ?>" alt="">`

Comment: nah, using ' instead of " will prevent you from accessing variables inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

Using glob instead of an array fixed the problem. PHP is including the . and double dot of the directory structure and therefore creating 2 empty images.